# How to store image in password protected folder on network

Tags: vb.net

We have a customer database with about 100,000 records.  We also have to scan and store their ID cards copies in the database. For the sake of database performance, I am storing the images on a network drive (shared folder) and the path in database. This shared folder is not password protected and is accessible to whosoever navigates to it. Now, I want to password protect the share folder and access it only through the vb.net application that I am developing. Kindly advice as to how to implement that or any other best solution in this scenario.

PS: This is my first project.

Comment: assuming that the id images are fairly small in size (a few KB) I think using the Db will be a lot simpler and will not involve additional cost (in terms of time). Also you will be able to retrieve the entire user data in a single query.

Comment: Create an account for your program to use and then have a look at the WindowsIndentity.Impersonate method.